# Android: trying to make a count down from dec 21 using GregorianCalendar class

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a simple app that will display a count down timer to December 21.

I have the following code

```
 GregorianCalendar gToday = new GregorianCalendar();
         GregorianCalendar gEndOfWorld = new GregorianCalendar();
         gEndOfWorld.set(2012,12,1);
```

My idea was to minus the 2 dates. but It seems like there is no method to subtract dates.  Is their a way to accomplish this?

Comment: `Calendar` months are 0-based, so the correct value of December is 11 or better: `java.util.Calendar.DECEMBER`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And if you want to make life easy then you use the Joda Time library and then calculate the number of days between today and the end of the world quite easily. See [this page](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/faq.html#datediff) for some examples.

```
   Days d = Days.daysBetween(today, endOfWorld);
   int days = d.getDays();
```

Comment: Hi,I cannot get the code to compile says Days does cannot be resolve to a type, I'm assuming i neeed to import a lib? I tried import java.util.days, and import java.util.*; did not work

Comment: The above solution uses the Joda Time library. You can download it from [Here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

you can calulate time difference like this

```
GregorianCalendar c1 = new GregorianCalendar();
      GregorianCalendar c2 = new GregorianCalendar();
      c1.setGregorianChange(date1);
      c2.setGregorianChange(date2);
      long differenceInMS = c1.getTimeInMillis() - c2.getTimeInMillis();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by the following way

```
        GregorianCalendar gToday = new GregorianCalendar();
        GregorianCalendar gEndOfWorld = new GregorianCalendar();
        gEndOfWorld.set(2012, 12, 1);
//Add below line for your requirement satisfaction to minus 2 dates
        gToday.add(Calendar.DATE, -2);
```